# While using the public app on the Bigcommerce, is the app uses the merchant specific OAuth token and store-hash for making store specific API calls?

Tags: bigcommerce

Do I need to maintain at my Public app host server database the individual set of OAuth token & store-hash pairs for all the merchants those will be installing my Public app from BigCommerce marketplace? So whenever they launch/use my public app from their store control panel, I need to pick up the relevant OAuth token and store-hash from the database for that merchant and then use them for making store specific API calls to that merchant store, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will end up needing to store the client id, access token, and store hash. It may be desirable to also keep additional user information such as first name and email address.

You can see an example of this in different languages, such as [Python using Flask framework](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-python-flask/blob/master/app.py).

There's a few pieces to this. Sample of db model being defined:

```
class User(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
bc_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'), nullable=False)
store = db.relationship('Store', backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

class Store(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
store_hash = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False, unique=True)
access_token = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
scope = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
```